# How to mock a @property method with "self" as parameter?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a property on only a specific instance of a class. To simplify the example, I have a `Thing` which gets initialised with a `name`, and based on this name the class will load a configuration file in a pre-defined location `/conf/{name}_conf.yaml`.

When testing, a couple of instances of `Thing` are created and I just want to override the configuration for one of these.

I commented below the initial code that I had to change to make it work:

```py
class Thing():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # I wasn't able to mock this:
        # self.configuration_name = f'/configuration/{self.name}_configuration.yaml'

    # @property   <- nor this
    def configuration_filename(self):
        return f'/configuration/{self.name}_configuration.yaml'
```

And in my tests, the mock should be able to take as parameter a different configuration file (specific to the test), but only be applied to the instance of `Thing` named `test_thing`.

I got it working with the above implementation like this:

```py
configuration_filename_orig = Thing.configuration_filename

def my_patched_configuration_filename(self, configuration_filename, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.slug == 'cmstest':
        return configuration_filename
    else:
        return configuration_filename_orig(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then I can "inject" a custom test configuration file for each test class like this:

```py
from functools import partial
from test.utils import my_patched_configuration_filename
...

@patch.object(Thing, 'configuration_filename', autospec=True, side_effect=partial(my_patched_configuration_filename, configuration_filename='testdata/test_1.yaml'))
class ConfigurationTests(TestCase):

     def test_1(self, mocked_conf):
         # test something

    def test_2(self, mocked_conf):
         # test something else

@patch.object(Thing, 'configuration_filename', autospec=True, side_effect=partial(my_patched_configuration_filename, configuration_filename='testdata/test_2.yaml'))
class ConfigurationTestsAdvanced(TestCase):

     def test_1(self, mocked_conf):
         # test something

    def test_2(self, mocked_conf):
         # test something else
```

Now... this works but I wonder if there's a way to do something similar but with a real property on the `Thing` class (either with the `@property` decorator or with the property initialised in the the `__init__` method).

I've spent a couple of hours trying different things... but the main issue seems that using `return_value` doesn't pass the `self` argument to the mock, so I can't use it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you use a [property mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=propertymock#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) to mock the property?

Comment: I tried, but as far as I can see the `PropertyMock` takes in a `return_value`, and I need it to be function depending on the instance (need the `self` arg). If I use a `PropertyMock` with a side effect, I don't get the `self` either. If there's a way with `PropertyMock`, I haven't found it :(

Answer (score 1):

ok there might be a better way but I got this working as follow:

- I can use the `@property` decorator on my class, that's what I want to mock:

```py
class Thing():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def configuration_filename(self):
        return f'/configuration/{self.name}_configuration.yaml'
```

- I create a new mock class, based on `Mock`:

```py
# first copy original
configuration_filename_orig = Thing.configuration_filename.__get__


class ConfigurationPropertyMock(Mock):

    # and here, add the `self` to the args
    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return self(obj, obj_type, *args, **kwargs)


def patched_filename(self, *args, **kwargs):
    configuration_filename = kwargs.pop('configuration_filename')
    if self.slug == 'cmstest' and configuration_filename:
        return configuration_filename
    else:
        return configuration_filename_orig(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

- And I patch the test class where I can pass a custom `configuration_filename`:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from tests.utils import ConfigurationPropertyMock, patched_filename
...

@patch('somewhere.Thing.configuration_filename',
       new_callable=ConfigurationPropertyMock,
       side_effect=partial(patched_filename, configuration_filename='test_conf.yaml'))
       )
class YAMLApiConfigurationTests(TestCase):

    def test_api_configuration_document(self, mocked_conf):
        # test here, the test configuration is loaded
        pass
```

Voilà :)

Comment: I think that's a reasonable solution.